# Specifying a log name for screen output without relying on .screenrc

Tags: command-line-interface, logging, gnu-screen, color

In a Bash script, I use "screen -L" to log executed commands in color. For example:

```
screen -L tree
```

Then we read the logfile with `less -R`.

When this script is executed, other screens are potentially running so we don't know which screenlog.* contains our output. I can't demand the user to customize his/her `.screenrc`.

Is there a way to specify a log name on command line or to read specific `.screenrc` commands?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file/37559327#37559327

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have a couple thoughts on this.  First, note you can control the startup screenrc when invoking screen via the `-c` command line switch.  Second, you can use environment variables in your .screenrc.  Putting this all together, here's a shell script to do something like what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF >/tmp/screenrc.$$
logfile /tmp/screenlog.$$
EOF

screen -c /tmp/screenrc.$$ -L
rm /tmp/screenrc.$$

echo "logfile is /tmp/screenlog.$$"
```

that script overrides the user screenrc and places the output in a specific file.  In this case I'm using `$$` to generate the file name by appending the script process name.  Note that you should generally use `mktemp` instead to create secure temporary files but I'm lazy right now.

Also this completely replaces the user `.screenrc`.  If you want to still read settings from that file, you should change the generated config file to something like this:

```
logfile /tmp/screenlog.$$
source $HOME/.screenrc
```

Answer (score 4):

In screen 4.06 and later, the log file can be specified directly on the command line with `-Logfile <name>`.

For earlier versions, the accepted answer is likely to be the clearest option.

(In screen 4.05 a log file name can confusingly be given as an optional argument to the `-L` option, which is a recipe for problems if someone tries to give a bare `-L` option as the last option: the command name gets misinterpreted as a log file name).

Comment: This is such an underrated answer!! Voting up

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
tree -C > tree.log
```

The `-C` option forces color on even when the output is not to a tty.

Similarly:

```
ls -l --color=always > ls.log
grep --color=always foo bar > grep.log
ack --color foo > ack.log
```

Utilities that output color often have ways to force it on when output is sent to a pipe or redirected.

Comment: After re-reading the question, my suspicion is that something like this might be more what's really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, there's a way to do it online.

Enter command mode in screen via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, and use the `logfile` command with the name of the file you want as argument:

```
logfile whatevernameyoulike.log
```

Source: Screen man page